# Need help understanding some swift MacOS crashes

Tags: swift, macos, crash, xib

I am trying to understand why the Preference panes for **HSTracker** (https://github.com/HearthSim/HSTracker/tree/2.1.10/HSTracker) are reporting crashes on the **viewDidLoad** method.

```
HSTracker
HSTracker.GeneralPreferences.viewDidLoad() -> () GeneralPreferences.swift:0
HSTracker
@objc HSTracker.GeneralPreferences.viewDidLoad() -> () <compiler-generated>:0
AppKit
-[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad]
HSTracker
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Preferences.PreferencesWindowController.init(preferencePanes: [Preferences.PreferencePane], style: Preferences.Preferences.Style, animated: Swift.Bool, hidesToolbarForSingleItem: Swift.Bool) -> Preferences.PreferencesWindowController PreferencesWindowController.swift:37
HSTracker
Preferences.PreferencesWindowController.init(preferencePanes: [Preferences.PreferencePane], style: Preferences.Preferences.Style, animated: Swift.Bool, hidesToolbarForSingleItem: Swift.Bool) -> Preferences.PreferencesWindowController <compiler-generated>:0
HSTracker
HSTracker.AppDelegate.preferences.getter : Preferences.PreferencesWindowController <compiler-generated>:0
HSTracker
@objc HSTracker.AppDelegate.openPreferences(Swift.AnyObject) -> () AppDelegate.swift:583
AppKit
-[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:]
HSTracker
main AppDelegate.swift:21
0x0 + 0
```

Using **atos**, I decoded the crash location to the very first line on the method:

https://github.com/HearthSim/HSTracker/blob/2.1.10/HSTracker/UIs/Preferences/GeneralPreferences.swift#L32

```
        notifyGameStart.state = Settings.notifyGameStart ? .on : .off
```

So why would it crash on that line, assuming all the IBOutlets are properly linked in the XIB file?

There is similarly strange crash when presenting a property sheet on this code:

```
newDeck = NewDeck(windowNibName: "NewDeck")
if let newDeck = newDeck {
    newDeck.setDelegate(self)
    newDeck.defaultClass = currentClass ?? nil
    self.window!.beginSheet(newDeck.window!, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

The crash happens on the **newDeck.window!** forced unwrap.

I can use some insights on why these two crashes happen and how to avoid/fix them.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you sure `newDeck.window` is not nil?

Comment: For that crash, it is `nil` unwrapping for sure, no doubt about it. I have seen similar issues when loading a window from NIB but I am wondering if this is a timing issue of sorts.